# mongodb find documents with field from other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have two collection on stores user data and another stores all invitations.

In invitation collection I only store two ids one is fromID and another is toID

I am able to get all the document array from invitations collection, but how to get the user detail from user collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB isn't a relational database and isn't the best choice to store such data. That being said, you can use the `$lookup` function as part of an `aggregate` query. [See the docs, here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `populate` to get user detail. that is assuming in your mongoose model you made the `toID` and `fromID` of type mongoose model and you set the correct ref. check the docs. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html